Air handler resonates loudly through return vents
My air handler resonates loudly when running the heat, at a medium pitch, cyclically. I can only hear it through return vents. I have a YouTube video here
It almost sounds like metal on metal vibration?
My question is: Is there anything obvious that I could check before calling the installer?
We didn't notice this noise while running AC during the summer, and this is our first time running the heat for fall.
Regards,

You obviously have something touching something else that's resonating.  You cannot hear this noise at the air handler itself, or through the registers—just the returns?  Is it louder at any particular returns?

I had a similar issues, loud vibration coming from return vents. In my case, it was due to restricted airflow resulting in abnormal air suction from those vent which caused the vibration.
